# Outputting method result to erb

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm working on an application that creates random sentences. I have it working as a console application, and want to make a Sinatra app which lets me display the sentences on the browser.

I have a variable @grammar that is populated from a form. I want to pass this into a method a few methods which work together to take in a string and generate a random sentence from it using a lot of logic. My rsg.erb file looks like this.

Where 'The waves portend like big yellow flowers tonight.' is the output of the  expand method. I would like to display this on the erb file so it is displayed on the browser.

How can I do that?

Comment: That's interesting. Do you have to have this calculation in the view? If you extracted it into a controller or helper, I'm quite positive it'd work.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:

```
<%= @grammar %>

<%-# Assigning values to the variables in first step %>
<%-
  rds = read_grammar_defs(@grammar) #get text from file and parse
  sds = rds.map { |rd| split_definition rd} #use split definition to make array of strings
  tgh = to_grammar_hash(sds) #create hash
  rs = expand(tgh) #create sentence
%>

<%-# Printing it in second step %>
<%= rs %>
```